# Where should my system and addons folders reside for PyroCMS?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, hosting, pyrocms

I have just completed a fresh install of PyroCMS on a dev server and it appears that the system and addons folder reside above the document root folder within "public_html".

PyroCMS is based off of CodeIgniter and every time I did a CodeIgniter install it always had me place the system folder below the document root for security purposes. Shouldn't this be true with the PyroCMS install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules require assets, which of course means HTTP access is required. We plan to eventually improve the Asset helper to GZIP/minify/combine everything and pass it through an "asset" controller, meaning images can be cached and resized, javascript can be squashed, etc.

Putting everything through a PHP file in this way means eventually you'll be able to have everything outside of the public folder, but for now you need direct access or you are entirely screwing with your chances of having a theme with images, css, javascript or icons.

Just don't tell Apache to serve PHP files as text/plain and you'll be absolutely fine. ;-)

Comment: So does this mean that the system folder can be outside of the document root or not?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: see above.